# Unsigned char * produce weird characters which make it always failed to compared

Tags: c++, sqlite, unsigned

I always have this problem with `unsigned char*` especially when it is the type that return from some function. For my problem is, I have a database and I want to select one of the column from the table. Then get the value with `sqlite3_column_text()`.

This is the code:

```
void check_username(std::string username)
{
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    std::string query = "SELECT username FROM bank_account WHERE username = '"+ username +"';";
   
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, query.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Move to result of query's row
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

    // Get the column value
    const unsigned char* result = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
    // Convert std::string username to unsigned char* for comparison with text in result
    const unsigned char* new_username = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(username.c_str());


    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    
    
    // THIS WILL FAILED TO COMPARE //
    if (new_username == result)
        std::cout << "It's match! << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "It's not match! << std::endl;
}
```

It says that `sqlite3_column_text()` return `unsigned char*` so that's why I store it in variable of same type:

`const unsigned char* result = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);`

And then as you can see, my function take `std::string` as parameters. So in order to compare it with the result from database, I convert it to unsigned char:

`const unsigned char* new_username = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(username.c_str());`

**Here's the problem:** at the end of the code it always failed to compare, it always get false even if the name is match. Then I tried to debug with `std::cout << result << std::endl;`
`std::cout << new_username << std::endl;`, here's the output:

```
�S�U
Harrypotter
```

So the one which get from `sqlite3_column_text()` produce that weird characters. So, I think that's why it always not match when I tried to compare.

So my question is, how is that happen? and what's the solution so  I can compare it?

Comment: You're comparing pointers. Try doing it the other way around, create a std::string from result and then compare the std::string variables.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't think there's no issue in that. As long as they both contain strings. I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
void check_username(const std::string& username) // added const&
{
....
    // Get the column value, create string from char*
    std::string new_username{ static_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0)) }; // <========

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    
    // now compare the std::string variables instead of pointers
    if (new_username == username)
        std::cout << "It's match! << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "It's not match! << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It failed. It can't store `sqlite3_column_text()` to `std::string` like that.

Comment: The error says: `no instance of constructor "std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (const unsigned char *)`

Comment: And I couldn't compile all the sql stuff..  oh the sql method returns a const unsigned char* I didn't notice that, std::string requires a const signed char*. Ehm try std::string new_username{ static_cast<const 
 char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0)) }; (Usually we ask for a compileable code example, but I can see that's hard with sql lite in the loop)

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`if (new_username == result)`

You cannot compare two separate pointers like that. Pointers are essentially just
memory addresses and considering that `result` and `new_username` refer to different locations in memory, the above condition will never be satisfied.

If you want to compare the *contents*, you have three options:

1. Use [`std::equal()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

   ```cpp
   #include <cstring>
   #include <algorithm>

   // Do prefer using `const std::string&` over just `std::string` in the parameter to avoid temporary copies
   void check_username(std::string const& username) {
       // ...

       const unsigned char* result = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);

       // ...

       if (std::equal(username.begin(), username.end(),
                      result, result + std::strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(result))))
           std::cout << "It's match!" << std::endl;
       else
           std::cout << "It's not match!" << std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. Use the [`operator==()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) comparison operator for strings:

   ```cpp
   #include <cstring>

   // ...

   void check_username(std::string const& username) {
       // ...

       const unsigned char* result = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);

       // ...

       if (username == std::string(result, result + std::strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(result))))
           std::cout << "It's match!" << std::endl;
       else
           std::cout << "It's not match!" << std::endl;
   }
   ```
3. Use [`std::strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp):

   ```cpp
   #include <cstring>

   // ...

   void check_username(std::string const& username) {
       // ...

       const unsigned char* result = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);

       // ...

       if (std::strcmp(&username[0], reinterpret_cast<const char*>(result)) == 0)
           std::cout << "It's match!" << std::endl;
       else
           std::cout << "It's not match!" << std::endl;
   }
   ```

Comment: It failed. All of it. Just like I said it always print "It's not match!". Even though I know it a same name.

Comment: @Kevinkun Did you try checking the values of `username` and `result` using a debugger or `std::cout` and see if they match?

Comment: Yeah it's match.

Comment: I just found the problem! It's on `sqlite3_finalize(stmt)`. It changes the value of `result` when it executed before I do comparison. So, that's why it always didn't match.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'm using the third.